# JAVA_HOME environment variable and Java JDK fun

Tags: java, java-home

I wanted to get Java running at 1.6xxx - I changed the JAVA_HOME variable and pointed it to the directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0._16.

I restart the PC - and I think I can check which version of Java my machine is pointing at - but it still points to the older version of Java e.g v1.5.0_16

Can you help me rejog my memory on correct setup for Java JDK?

[image: java home]

Comment: check your PATH variable and see which version of java is present on that.

Comment: I have tried changing the PATH variable and JAVA_HOME variable to point to the same dir - but I still get the same result using the java -version command - 1.5.0.16 etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to reset your path variable to point to 1.6

something like
[image]

Additionally, make sure the variable `JAVA_HOME` is also set with the above location.

Comment: My Java_Home and my Path Varaible point to the java version 1.6.0_19, but in the cmd java -version shows me java version 1.6.0_20. Because i made an update via the java-Updater?

Comment: @cuh java-Updater !! interesting, how ? which O.S. ?

Comment: Windows 7. In the jre/bin Directory start Java Control Panel: javacpl. you can (de-)activate automatic update notifications. My Path points to jdk 1.6.0_19 but java in cmd is linked to the jre6 version 1.6.0_20.

Comment: @cuh: Is there is a java (a different one) in your system folder by any chance?

Comment: @cuh may be updation process inturrepted and the effect wasn't rolled back properly..may be..i am not sure

Comment: I have tried changing the PATH variable and JAVA_HOME variable to point to the same dir - but I still get the same result using the java -version command - 1.5.0.16 etc.

Comment: @Vidar Have you restart your command prompt after making change ?

Comment: try executing this at command prompt,  echo %PATH%   does it contain newer path ?

Comment: @org.life.java - yes it contains the new path

Comment: can you post your output of echo %PATH%

Comment: @org.life.java - OK, here it is:                                      D:\oracle\ora92\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.1.8\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adaptec Shared\System;c:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin;C:\ant\bin;C:\axis2-1.4.1\bin;C:\Sun\jwsdp-2.0\jaxb\bin

Comment: @Vidar , I doubt the same thing , there are two executable `java` in path, remove `C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.1.8\bin` from path and then restart command prompt no need to reboot machine

Comment: @org.life.java - just tried that, made no difference - still 1.5xxx

Comment: @Vidar, Then I would suggest reinstalling it. :-)

Comment: @org.life.java - ok this may be where I went wrong - I didn't exactly install the jdk - I just copied the directory jdk1.6.0_16 from another PC to my PC - thinking that it didn't require any windows specific install program - now I guess it does? Does it alter the registry?

Comment: @Vidar I would strongly recommend you to simply delete that dir, and install it from standard setup.

Answer (score 6):

JAVA_HOME is used by other applications, such as Tomcat. Windows just checks the PATH environment variable for locations where it can find the java executable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the cmd shell:

```
> java -version
java version "1.5.0_16"
> set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
> java -version
```

Comment: That wouldn't work since you are appending `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` _after_ the existing path list - Windows will still find the older `java.exe` first. Should be `set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%` instead.

Comment: @Peter, agree, didn't pay attention, the old Java *was* on the path so it has to be added at the beginning for this demo. But obviously, replacing the old entry is the norma solution ;)

Comment: Yes indeed. Btw I wasn't the downvoter - I think your demo idea is good and this issue is trivial to fix.

Answer (score 0):

This Image will explain all steps.
[image]

For More [Explanation](http://hints.steptoinstall.com/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-in-windows-7-8-for-java.html)