# Java installation

Tags: java, tomcat8

I have an application in production which runs on java 6. I need to deploy another application which uses Tomcat8 and for Tomcat8 installation i need latest version of Java 1.8 installed in the same box.

I don't want to change any of the existing parameters, environmental variables so that the old application already running should not stop working. So i don't want to use msi installer (exe) for Jdk installation.

How do I install new version of Java without disrupting the previous version.  Also how do i install Java in production without using the exe.

Comment: In production on which operating system/distribution? And are you sure, this question doesn't rather belong over to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: Simply install it in another directory than the already installed Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

Simply download the server JRE. It's a tar.gz file not an exe.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html

Comment: it is for JRE. I am looking for JDK.

Comment: Why do you want a JDK? Tomcat doesn't require that: 
Apache Tomcat 8.5 requires a Java Standard Edition Runtime
Environment (JRE) version 7 or later.

Comment: server.bat uses java_home and jre_home both.

Comment: C:\installation\apache-tomcat-8.5.4\bin>service.bat install
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

Comment: It's completly valid to point JAVA_HOME to a JRE i.e. on a server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601827/which-one-should-java-home-to-point-jdk-or-jre

Comment: and Tomcat doesn't need anything from JDK it uses Eclipse compiler to complie JSPs

Comment: So do you mean i don't need jdk for a standalone tomcat installation.if so, what should i do in server.bat where it is looking for JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME. If i make both same as JRE_HOME, then too throws the error at the line:if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe" goto noJavaHome.  I need to install and start tomcat as a service. I am not installing it for eclipse.

Comment: server.bat, there is clear print statement as:echo The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
echo NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

Answer (score 0):

if its a linux machine, Use the below

```
apt-cache search jdk
```

Select the required jdk and give the command

```
apt-get install jdk_name_selected
```

Do this as root user, or a sudo user