# Whats the difference between the "java" file found in "jdk1.8.0_121/bin" and the one that's in "jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin"?

Tags: java, environment-variables, java-home

I need to set the JAVA_HOME variable and I don't know which route I have to choose or if it's the same one or another.

I have two files named "java" one is into the "jdk/bin" folder and the another one is into "jdk/jre/bin" folder. What's the difference between them? Because searching over internet I see that there are people using one and another people using the other.

Comment: See [which one should JAVA_HOME to point, JDK or JRE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601827/which-one-should-java-home-to-point-jdk-or-jre), `JAVA_HOME` helps the system find the right binary in `bin`folders.

Comment: `jre/bin` (Java Runtime Environment) is usually used when you're running software that uses java, but you don't want to actually compile java source code. `idk/bin` is used when you want to develop software using Java (Java Development Kit).

Comment: So the route for JAVA_HOME in the /etc/environment where should be pointing at? JDK?

Comment: Thank you @Neo X I'll read it. Thanks David for your answer too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whats the difference between the `java` file found in `jdk1.8.0_121/bin` and the one that's in `jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin`?

There is no difference in recent versions of Java; e.g. Java 8 or later.  I have heard that there were small differences in older versions.

> So the route for JAVA_HOME in the /etc/environment where should be pointing at?

The `JAVA_HOME` variable should point to the Java installation directory; i.e. `jdk1.8.0_121` in your case.

If you are configuring the `PATH` variable to explicitly contain a Java `bin` directory<sup>1</sup>, you would normally use `jdk1.8.0_121/bin` so that the development tools are on the command search path.

Note that `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` serve different purposes.

- `JAVA_HOME` is used to tell 3rd-party tools where the Java installation is.
- `PATH` is used by the shell to resolve command names.

---

<sup>1 - The other way to do it on Linux is to use the `alternatives` tool.</sup>