# System is pointing to JDK in windows but still getting error messages

Tags: java

while trying to create a web module project throwing an error

but my ENV variables and JAVA_HOME are already pointing to correct JDK folder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKbo6.png)

Comment: %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: Try re-starting system, does the trick most of the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [which one should JAVA\_HOME to point, JDK or JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601827/which-one-should-java-home-to-point-jdk-or-jre)

Comment: tried evrything ! not working

Comment: hey, what is the error msg?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your JAVA_HOME path to **C:\Program Files\jdk1.8.0_141\bin**. I believe you need to point it to the folder the executable (java.exe) is located in.

Comment: I changed it to C:\Program Files\jdk1.8.0_141\bin but still it is showing the same error.

Comment: go to the command prompt ( new window of command prompt) and run "echo %Path%"  and see if it matches with the path you set . Does it contain "C:\Program Files\jdk1.8.0_141\bin"
Ideally your JAVA_HOME should be JAVA_HOME path to C:\Program Files\jdk1.8.0_141 and your Path should be %JAVA_HOME%\bin;and the renaming path as is

Comment: Sry,but its not working either !

Comment: JAVA_HOME should not point to /bin

Answer (score 1):

What I do is close to what you use, but not quite the same. I set `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\jdk1.8.0_141` (as I install the JDK at the root C:\ rather than in program files. I don't like spaces in path names and I don't like drilling down to get to the JDK. Personal preference and should not matter.) The difference is not using \bin on the end. Then for my PATH variable, I have `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;...`. That is, tack the \bin in the PATH not the JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Yes Sure, but it is not making a difference in my system. The Path is
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;

Comment: ENV var Path --- >> %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%MAVEN_HOME%;