# Netbeans IDE has reconfigured itself, need help resetting to previous view

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

For some reason my Netbeans IDE view has changed and I can no longer use it to compile and run code because the windows are now empty. See the screen shot below.

Can someone point me in the right direction to get it back to normal again?

[image: Screen shot of blank NetBeans]

Comment: The first thing to do is [1] Restart NetBeans. [2] Locate and open the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**). If NetBeans is so broken that that does not work, open the file  in any text editor. See [Where do I find the NetBeans log file...?](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile). [3] Update your question with the content of that log.

Comment: thanks kindly but the log is 6000 chars and the post only allows for 3000, any ideas how to share? Have saved as .txt/.rtf file

Edit: this seems to have oocured after downloaded JDK13 for an IDE (IntelliJ) my university want us to use and I was prompted to allow Java access by my machine (macOS)

Comment: [1] OK. Don't worry about the log after all, since your problem is probably that NetBeans 8.2 is trying to use JDK 13, but it does not support any JDK > 8. [2] If you need to use NetBeans 8.2 then you **must** have JDK 8 installed, and then configure NetBeans 8.2 to use JDK 8. [See this SO answer for details on how to do that, by editing **netbeans.conf**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60427665/2985643). [3] Alternatively, [download and install release 11.2 of Apache NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/) and use that instead of 8.2, since it supports the use of JDK 13.

Comment: outstanding. Massive appreciation for your help, I've been using this IDE since the jump to work on my java programming it would have been a real inconvenience to not have access to it while learning the new IDE. Thanks again

Comment: Cool. One final point since you will be using Intelij IDEA with JDK 13: it is completely safe to also download and install the latest release of NetBeans (11.2) and configure it to use JDK 13 if you are so inclined. NetBeans 8.2 and NetBeans 11.2 won't know anything about each other, and will not interfere with each other at all.