# Why should JAVA_HOME environment variable value point to SDK directory instead of bin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm

Generally inorder to run Java applications we set JAVA_HOME value to java sdk directory/bin

But when this set and I try opening Android Studio it gives be an error saying JVM is not configured in your machine and doesn't open up.

If we reconfigure the JAVA_HOME to only java sdk directory path it works fine. But I wonder why this is  happening??

### If it is reconfigured to sdk path then my other java application don't work. Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Update: Please find image below when JAVA_HOME var is conifgured to right JDK dir, javac doesn't execute in command prompt

[image]

Thanks,
Nav.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898684/android-studio-no-jvm-installation-found

Comment: What other Java application doesn't work? Note that JAVA_HOME isn't a Java setting. It's a setting used by other applications that need to know where Java is. Different applications might use JAVA_HOME differently.

Comment: "Generally inorder to run Java applications we set JAVA_HOME value to java sdk directory/bin" -- no. Traditionally, `JAVA_HOME` is set to the JRE or SDK main directory. The `bin/` subdirectory might be in your `PATH`, though. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102022/what-does-the-java-home-environment-variable-do. "If it is reconfigured to sdk path then my other java application don't work" -- then there is a problem with those other applications.

Comment: @CommonsWare As suggested I have changed the values, AndroidStudio works fine but when I enter javac in command prompt it gives me error as Not Recoginzed.

Comment: if it is not recognized then you need to add the bin folder to the path, then close the CMD then open another one (the javahome should not be the bin, though)

Comment: Yup I have done that as can be seen in the image above...but still I get this error msg...Thanks

Answer (score 12):

> Generally inorder to run Java applications we set JAVA_HOME value to java sdk directory/bin

No. Traditionally, JAVA_HOME is set to the JRE or SDK main directory. The bin/ subdirectory might be in your PATH, though.

> I have changed the values, AndroidStudio works fine but when I enter javac in command prompt it gives me error as Not Recoginzed

That is because your `PATH` is wrong. Your `PATH` needs to point to the `bin/` directory within your Java SDK. My guess is that your `PATH` is referencing `JAVA_HOME`, but assuming (incorrectly) that `JAVA_HOME` points to that `bin/` directory. Just change your `PATH` to ensure that it picks up the `bin/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

the java_home should not include bin
but you should add /bin when you add java_home to path
like this:
export JAVA_HOME=.../jdk-xx/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:PATH