# DataStax not finding JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, datastax-enterprise

Installed DataStax 4.8.11 on Ubuntu 14.04 (Sparks/Analytics mode) using the Installer, the install was successful, but the start fails. JAVA is installed and in PATH etc but Cassandra unable to find:

```
@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo service dse start
Java executable not found (hint: set JAVA_HOME)
@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/jdk1.8.0_111
@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Thanks

Comment: @Alexander I perhaps dont have multiple java versions (I cant ever be completely sure on Linux) ~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
Based on the link I tried multiple alternative for PATH etc/environment (original setup), then .bashrc (Both did not work). Then added PATH to .profile - now I cant even login into the machine

Comment: Reconfirming I just have 1 version of Java, and JAVA_HOME is correctly setup. So likely something to do with DataStax install (??)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have been able to make it work is by setting Env in the command itself as follows:

```
sudo env PATH="$PATH" service dse start
```

So for all dse commands I need to set PATH - kinda cumbersome.

This has something to do with [Environment variables when run with 'sudo'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57915/environment-variables-when-run-with-sudo) (whatever). (Thanks to Ubuntu forum).
I would have expected the Datastax 'Installer' to take care of all this.

The installer does a very poor job, and also does not set DSE or CASSANDRA HOME, does not put anything in PATH. And also the documentation is wrong - per docs the binary files should be in /usr/bin but they actually are in /usr/share/dse/bin (it takes a little bit of doing to actually find this location).

@DataStax you guys can try see what the issue is and try fix. This type of installation (basic default) shouldn't turn out to a research project- especially when I am using the "Installer". (took me all of 2 days).

Answer (score 0):

I added `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java` to the appropriate locations in the following files:

- `/etc/default/dse`
- `/etc/dse/*.sh`

Another thing to be aware of is that after doing `/etc/init.d/dse restart` the services will take a while to appear.

Also [1] is handy.

[1] [what is the reason for the existence of the JAVA_HOME environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102022/what-does-the-java-home-environment-variable-do)