# Is it mandatory to give only JAVA_HOME as variable name while setting environment variable for java?

Tags: java

Iam having doubt on this, Is it mandatory to give only JAVA_HOME as variable name while setting environment variable for java?. I saw so many articles and videos everywhere same variable name JAVA_HOME. (Even for android also only ANDROID_HOME). What is the problem if we give some other variable name? can any one help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well some other variable name might not cause any problems, but it wouldn't do the job of setting the Java home directory! Assuming you mean `JAVA_HOME=/some/dir java ...`, that's not an argument to `java`, that's setting an environment variable.

Comment: Look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102022/what-is-the-reason-for-the-existence-of-the-java-home-environment-variable

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 3):

You can set some other name but some application that use java try to search for "JAVA_HOME" in order to setup and make itself running , say some IDE that uses java, by default it searches for that environmental variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rishabh Durgar. Is it the same reason in case of other variable setting like ANDROID_HOME?

Comment: Absolutely Correct.

Answer (score 1):

`JAVA_HOME` is the standard environment variable name for where Java resides on your system. If you change it to be `JAVA_HOME_OTHER` for example, any Java application relying on `JAVA_HOME` env variable to bet set will fail to run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SergeyB. Is JAVA_HOME like key word a?

Comment: It's more of a naming convention - a universally accepted env var for Java's location.