# Setting environmental variables for PlayonLinux

Tags: java, linux

So I just installed android studio for PlayOnLinux and it was fine.  When I try to start it, it is looking for `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable to be set to the jdk.

I have the jdk installed in my virtual windows directory as well as on linux.  How do I set an environmental variable in PlayOnLinux?

I tried adding `export JAVA_HOME=/jdk-installation`  to `.bash.sh`  and `/home/myUser/playonlinux-bash.sh` but neither did anything.  Is it somewhere in the GUI?

Comment: Have you sourced the file applying changes ?

Comment: I applied the changes if that's what you mean.  I feel like my path might possibly be incorrect:                                                                                                        export JAVA_HOME=/home/myUser/dosdevices/z:/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_201

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set java\_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2619584/608639), [what is the reason for the existence of the JAVA_HOME environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5102022/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

For future people trying to figure this out: 
I don't think /etc/profile affects PlayOnLinux...  I finally found the correct file at

```
          /home/myUser/dosdevices/z:/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux
```

and added the

```
          export JAVA_HOME=/home/myUser/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/java/drive_c/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.8.0_201
```

I have other problems running android studio but this is for anyone that wants to set environmental variables in PlayOnLinux

Answer (score 0):

Open file  `/etc/profile` in edit mode

```
vim /etc/profile
```

Add below path

```
export JAVA_HOME="jdk-installation"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Source the file for applying the change

```
source /etc/profile
```