# Do I need to set java JDK path in user variables or system variables?

Tags: java, path, java-home

I am new in java programming. I am currently using Windows. Recently I saw a video tutorial from YouTube that the instructor was setting `java JDK path` in system variables then created a new variable called `JAVA_HOME`.

Now I saw in `javaTpoint tutorial` that they were setting the path in user variables didn't create any `JAVA_HOME` variable.

So my question is what is the difference between the set path in user variables and system variables? Which one do I have to set? and what's all about `JAVA_HOME`?

I didn't found any proper explanation on this. Your answer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the reason for the existence of the JAVA\_HOME environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102022/what-is-the-reason-for-the-existence-of-the-java-home-environment-variable)

Comment: JAVA_HOME isn't strictly necessary because the JDK doesn't use it. Other Java applications however do use it, so some tutorials have you set it as a precaution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set it as a user variable, it's only available to the current user. If you set it as a system variable, it's available for all users. i.e. if you log out of Windows and log in with a different user, you won't have the JDK on your system path if you set it as a user variable. If it's your personal computer and you only have one account, it doesn't matter too much. I'd recommend setting it as a system variable.

`JAVA_HOME` is used by Gradle and Maven build tools (and some other things) to know where the root directory of your JDK is located. It should point to the folder where the `bin` folder is located, ie `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.7`. If you're just starting out, I wouldn't worry about it too much. It's not necessary until you start using more complex tools for development.

Comment: Adding extra points. If you want to give all the users to a one version of java as a base user system variable section and the current user or any user need a specific then you can use user variable section to point out specific version of java to that user only.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is user variables means the variable will only be able to be used & called by the user it was created by. On the other hand, for system variables, all users can use that variable.

I would recommend setting it to the system variables for compatibility, accessibility and less chance of creating errors of variable not found.